# List all users in a Windows domain

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-server-2008

Is there a command to view all users on a Windows domain?

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

> net user

lists all users.

Comment: That only seems to show users for **this** computer and not for the entire domain. even if I do `NET USER /DOMAIN`...

Comment: @Neal /DOMIAN is supposed to work, you can look for other answers...

Comment: this should work, but realize that if you are on some versions of windows they are not allowed to join a domain so you won't get the same result as a machine who is. home professional, won't but ultimate will for instance

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are on Windows Server 2008. If you have R2, then you have Powershell With AD Modules so you can do:

```
Get-ADUser
```

Comment: Windows server 2008. I am not sure where you see 2003...

Comment: Yup, I meant 2008, but have 2003 on the brain because of some stuff that I am working on. 2008R2 is the OS that would have the AD modules already present.

Answer (score 2):

```
dsquery user
```

This will only show the first 100 records though.  You have to add the `-limit` parameter to show more.  Of course this will show the full DN, if you want more specific info you specify other parameters to do this.  I would recommend looking at the dsquery user page on Technet [1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725702%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: That does not work at all. `'dsquery' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: It is available if you have the Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) server role installed.  If the computer you are trying to do this on is not an AD controller I believe you can install the RSAT tools to use the ds* commands: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731420(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: did you run this from the server?

Comment: @uSlackr yes, I ran it from the server. But I do not belive I am an admin on that box.